# Change MonoDevelop SubVersion End-Point

Tags: svn, mono, monodevelop

I simply cannot figure out or find how to change the end-point for version control in MonoDevelop.

I changed my repository to a diffrent IP address and now I can't figure out where to make this change in my Mono project configuration.  None of the version control properties in the project I've found have any end-point listed.  It seems like a simple enough concept?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this change in MonoDevelop. You'll have to use an external tool.